# MDK: Format Simple Property as Number

Tags: odata, sap-business-application-studio, sap-mobile-services

I have a "QTY" field (simple property) on a page whose value is used in a Function Import. The Function Import expects a Number type.

The error I get in BAS is:

> Incorrect type. Expected "number".

How do I set this as a number? There is nothing in the simple property to says it's a number type, other than the "Keyboard Type".

Adding `$(N,...)` still shows as an error, but deploys fine.

[image: Action Error]

[image: Properties]

Comment: This question is not related to SAPUI5 but to MDK ("SAP Mobile Development Kit"). As this is the 1st valid MDK question on Stack Overflow, I just created a tag for it (`sap-mdk`).

Comment: Is the backend service based on OData V2 or OData V4?

Comment: Thanks for that.  The backend is ODataV2.  It seems to be a parser issue in BAS itself, as the app deploys fine and the app works, but BAS (and the MDK validator) show it as an error even when it's formatted using $(N,...).

Would you happen to know the GIT repo for BAS/MDK so I can raise it as a bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither BAS nor MDK is open-source (despite heavily relying on open-source in their core components). If you're a paying SAP customer, please create an incident at https://support.sap.com/en/index.html. Otherwise, you could also try reporting the issue at https://answers.sap.com/questions/ask.html?primaryTagId=73555000100800001081 or https://github.com/SAP-samples/cloud-mdk-samples/issues or https://github.com/SAP-samples/cloud-mdk-tutorial-samples/issues

Comment: Thank you @BoghyonHoffmann, much appreciated. I'll raise a ticket.

Comment: Were you able to create a ticket? Would be nice if future readers could also get updates regarding this issue.